# Set "selected" value of dynamicly changed html select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I hava an HTML `<select>` that has been filled with AJAX from JSON.

Now I want to set the selected value of the list by using JavaScript.

I have tried this way:

```
document.getElementById("selectID").value = value
```

and using jQuery:

```
$('#selectID').val(value)
```

but this doesn't work with my list filled with AJAX, while works with other "normal" HTML `<select>`.

Can you help me?

Comment: You need to provide more of your code before we can be of any help.

Comment: Your jQuery selector is wrong.

Comment: It should be `$('#selectID').val(value)` and are you waiting for the AJAX response to return before setting it? Need to see more code.

Comment: To start $('selectID') should be $('#selectID')

Comment: You need to call it in your AJAX success callback.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your value is indeed the value and not the text of the option tag.

```
<option value="someValue">someText<option/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Select option values are populated after ajax call response,Either try to put the script in
success handler of ajax call or use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method of jquery on option selection.

`.on() method` is used to bind the events even on the element which are loaded after page load.

Answer (score -1):

Set the `selectedIndex` of your `select` element to the one you want.

http://help.dottoro.com/ljsthorn.php

**For example:**

```
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
select.selectedIndex = 2;
```

this will set it to index '2'. Just know which index your value is at. If you don't, then just do `indexOf` and look for it.

Comment: No, it's not. `$('#selectID').val(value)` should work yet it doesn't indicating that the OP isn't waiting for the AJAX response or not using the proper selector.

Comment: yes it is. I am using the proper DOM API to set it, this is the one and true way. You kidding me right? do you even know how to work with the DOM? he asks how to set it after the select's options had changed.

Comment: I'm not saying your syntax is incorrect, I'm saying the OP is doing something wrong with the AJAX call or the selector to use the response. As he said, "this doesn't work with my list filled with AJAX, while works with other "normal" HTML <select>"

Comment: Did you even try what I wrote...? because I did, and this works no matter if the content has changed.

Comment: You're both making assumptions that OP should have provided in the question, and are wasting your time bickering about it when you should be asking him for clarification.

Comment: I perfectly understood what he meant. It's not difficult at all.